# glm operation over vectors return incorrect values

Tags: c++, floating-point, precision, glm

Glm uses float internally and evaluates values with very high precision. The problem is that regular operations with such values can return incorrect results. Consider this gdb output:

```
49                              return glm::normalize(coord - center);
(gdb) p coord
$1 = {{x = -1.30530175e+38, r = -1.30530175e+38, s = -1.30530175e+38}, {y = -2.65845583e+36, g = -2.65845583e+36, 
    t = -2.65845583e+36}, {z = 3.40282347e+38, b = 3.40282347e+38, p = 3.40282347e+38}}
(gdb) p center
$2 = {{x = -2, r = -2, s = -2}, {y = 0, g = 0, t = 0}, {z = 8, b = 8, p = 8}}
(gdb)
```

We have the `coord` vector the values of which have lots of decimal spaces and the `center` vector the values of which don't have any decimal places at all. The result of `glm::normalize` over these vectors is as follows:

```
Value returned is $14 = {{x = -0, r = -0, s = -0}, {y = -0, g = -0, t = -0}, {z = 0, b = 0, p = 0}}
```

It's clear that the normal vector can't be a zero vector. And this is the place inside glm library where everything goes wrong:

```
710                             v1.y * v2.y,
(gdb) p v1.y * v2.y
$6 = inf
(gdb) p v1.y
$7 = -2.65845583e+36
(gdb) p v2.y
$8 = -2.65845583e+36
(gdb)
```

This seems to be an overflow, but I'm not sure. If it is, is there a way to force glm to use `double` instead of `float` or is there an other way to fix this?

Comment: It's a nice story of your investigation of the issue. But how can SO users help you if you haven't posted a [mcve]? It's absolutely unclear what those `coord`, `center`, `v1`, `v2` are.

Comment: Given the implementation, `v * inversesqrt(dot(v, v))` it's no wonder it overflows. You could either rethink your algorithm to avoid such huge values or reimplement this function with intermediate scaling.

Comment: See here: https://github.com/gagern/gnulib/blob/master/lib/hypot.c

Answer (score 0):

Like [Evg supports Moderator Strike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1625187/evg-supports-moderator-strike) mentioned, in a case like this we need to normalize large values to avoid overflow